# WP Divi theme How to make all the pages / post to full width by default

Tags: wordpress

I am using Divi theme for WordPress project.

I would like to change all the page / post / product layout to full width by default instead of right side bar.

Please help how to do this. There is no default theme option available for that ont the admin side.

Thank you,
-Gideon

Comment: It is not a question for SO, this is request for freelance site.

Answer (score 1):

you can create layout template as fullwidth and inherit your pages from that template. To achieve that go to "Divi menu">"Divi library"

[image]

[image]

another solution is using this css code in "Divi">"Theme Options">"General">"Custom CSS":

```css
#sidebar{display: none;}
#left-area{width: 100%;}
#main-content .container:before {
width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alireza for the answer.

Comment: You should also set `#left-area`'s padding to `0 !important;`.